# Show and execute

Tags: foreach, makefile

In this makefile

```
dirs = $(shell ls)
clean:
    $(foreach dir,$(dirs),echo $(dir);)
```

The output is

```
$ make clean
echo bin; echo install.sh; echo Makefile; echo README.md; echo utils;
bin
install.sh
Makefile
README.md
utils
```

Why does it first show the command, then execute it?
How I can omit the first line?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Prepend the command with the @ character.  Example:

```
dirs = $(shell ls)
clean:
    @$(foreach dir,$(dirs),echo $(dir);)
```

Answer (score 6):

From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) ([5.2 Recipe Echoing](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html#Echoing), bold emphasis mine):

> **Normally *make* prints each line of the recipe before it is executed**. We call this *echo*ing because it gives the appearance that you are typing the lines yourself.
>
> **When a line starts with `@`, the echoing of that line is suppressed**. The `@` is discarded before the line is passed to the shell. *[...]*

---

Alternatively:

> The `-s` or `--silent` flag to *make* prevents all echoing, as if all recipes started with `@`.