# stop on error when target of makefile rule is a foreach function

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile that defines several rules where the target is a foreach function.

```
$(foreach var,$(list), $($(var)_stuff) $($(var)_more_stuff)):
    @echo Building $@ from $^...
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) ...
```

Is there any way to get make to quit when encountering an error without going through the entire list.

Comment: Wouldn't `make` exit on the first error unless you've passed `-k` command line option?

Comment: Not when it's done this way apparently.  The forloop continues.  I'm not sure this format is even a "RULE".  But it works

Comment: I'm... not sure what to say. Could you give us a minimal complete example so that we can see what `$($(var)_stuff)` is supposed to do? And maybe explain what kind of error you foresee?

Comment: It's insanely complex, and should be irrelevant to the question.  the $(CC) compiles a file with options expanded from the foreach text.  Only when one of those compilations fails, it continues on.  it won't stop automatically *I THINK* because there are no dependencies listed.  I'm looking for a way to make it stop.

Comment: What is that first line supposed to do? Do you expect the `foreach` statement to expand into a list of targets?

Comment: It does, It works, I'm trying to modify it for debugging purposes.

Comment: @8bitwide: The `foreach` is completely evaluated and substituted before any of the rules are executed.  So the behaviour of this should be identical to as if you had hardcoded the rule without using the `foreach`.  In other words, it's not directly relevant to the problem.  With that in mind, could you construct a simpler and more representative test-case for us to look at?

Answer (score 14):

One workaround is to "manually" invoke `exit` on failure.

For example, assume we have a directory called `scripts` with a number of shell scripts (with filenames that end with `.sh`) that we want to execute.

Then a variable declaration like this:

```
LIST_OF_SCRIPTS ?= $(wildcard scripts/*.sh)
```

will give us a list of those scripts, and a target like this:

```
run-all-scripts
  @$(foreach scriptfile,$(LIST_OF_SCRIPTS),$(scriptfile);)
```

will run all of those scripts, but as you note, the foreach loop will keep going whether or not one of the scripts returns an error code.  Adding a `|| exit` to the command will force the subcommand to exit on error, which Make will then treat as a failure.

E.g.,

```
run-all-scripts
  @$(foreach scriptfile,$(LIST_OF_SCRIPTS),$(scriptfile) || exit;)
```

will do what you want (I believe).

Specifically, using your pseudo-code example, I think you want something like this:

```
$(foreach var,$(list), $($(var)_stuff) $($(var)_more_stuff)):
    @echo Building $@ from $^...
    ($(CC) $(FLAGS) ...) || exit
```

(where all I've changed is wrapping the `(CC) $(FLAGS) ...` bit in parens and appending `|| exit` to make it fail on error).

Comment: I just ran into this issue with foreach loops not terminating on error, and this solution worked for me.  @Oleg's got the reason why it doesn't terminate without explicitly checking the error code.  Thanks for this solution!!

Comment: Thank you, adding  '|| exit' was the only feasible thing in my environment and it worked.

Answer (score 10):

The `foreach` is completely evaluated and substituted before *any* of the rules are executed. So the behaviour of this should be identical to as if you had hardcoded the rule without using the `foreach`. In other words, it's not directly relevant to the problem.

There are only a few possible explanations for what you're seeing, mostly described in the manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors):

- You are running Make with `-k` or `--keep-going`
- You are running Make with `-i` or `--ignore-errors`
- Your targets is defined as prerequisites of the special `.IGNORE` target
- Your recipe starts with a `-`
- Your recipe isn't actually returning a non-zero exit status

Comment: From everything I can find documentation-wise you are right.  But I'm not using -k or -keepgoing, - I or --Ignore-errors.  no .IGNORE anywhere in the make file.  None of the reciptes start with - they all start with c:/ghs/ppc424/ccppc.  And I finally figured out how to check the exit status.  And it's 1.  So I am at a loose

Comment: I'm going to try to create a simpler example that I can post the entire code to.

Comment: @8bitwide: Cool.  If you create a simpler example, I'll be happy to update my answer if I can spot anything new.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure about your example, but maybe problem is in `;` - look at [Makefile : show and execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498727/makefile-show-and-execute):

```
dirs = $(shell ls)
clean:
    $(foreach dir,$(dirs),echo $(dir);)
```

produce:

```
$ make clean
echo bin; echo install.sh; echo Makefile; echo README.md; echo utils;
```

So make check exit code only for last command: `echo utils`.

Comment: `set -e` would presumably fix this.